# Pandas Conditional Statement and Replace

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
                      col_1                  col_2                 col_3          col_4
0                         1          security team     steve@example.com
1         james@example.com                   chef           testing.csv
2         megan@example.com
```

I want to implement this logic:

```
If column 1 contains a value that contains an @ sign, then replace column 4 with that column
else check column 2 and implement the same logic
else check column 3 and implement the same logic
else column 4 remains an empty string
```

My output will look like this:

```
                     col_1                  col_2                 col_3                  col_4
0                         1          security team     steve@example.com     steve@example.com
1         james@example.com                   chef           testing.csv     james@example.com
2         megan@example.com                                                  megan@example.com
```

I thought about trying to use a Numpy select statement somehow, but I believe that may be too difficult.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what if col_1 AND col_2 contain @?

Comment: That's not possible in this dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Solution if some rows has multiple values with `@` then email are joined by `,`:

```
s = df.stack(dropna=False)
df['col_4'] = s[s.str.contains('@', na=False)].groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
print (df)
               col_1          col_2              col_3              col_4
0                  1  security team  steve@example.com  steve@example.com
1  james@example.com           chef        testing.csv  james@example.com
2  megan@example.com            NaN                NaN  megan@example.com
```

Another idea with list comprehension:

```
df['col_4'] = [','.join(y for y in x if '@' in y) for x in df.fillna('').to_numpy()]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm calling it a night, but I'll play around with this later and let you know how it worked for me.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: This does 99% of what I need it to do. There are some email addresses that are wrapped in double quotes that are messing things up. I need to figure out how I am doing to make this work for those. I need to split them vertically and then play around with this some more.

Comment: @LunchBox - Can you add some examples?